# Significance of $ \lambda $ in Basis Pursuit

Tags: signal-analysis, compressive-sensing, optimization, convex-optimization

In basis Pursuit, L1 minimization is done to perform compressed sensing. In the literature there is a $ \lambda $ parameter used as a regularizer.

What is its significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 forms of the Basis Pursuit problem:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{The $ \lambda $ Form:} & \quad && \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{The $ \epsilon$ Form:} && \quad & \arg \min_{x} {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
& \text{subject to} &&  \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} \leq \epsilon
\end{align*}$$

Sometimes it is more intuitive to have a look on the $ \epsilon $ form as it tell us exactly the trade off.
The lower $ \epsilon $ it means we require teh solution to hold the Linear Equation and we pay for that with the $ {L}_{1} $ Norm of the solution.

The nice things is that for any value $ \epsilon $ we can find $ \lambda $ for the other form in such way the generate the same solution:

$$ \forall \epsilon, \; \exists \lambda : x \left( \epsilon \right) = x \left
( \lambda \right) $$

Where $ x \left( \epsilon \right) $ and $ x \left ( \lambda \right) $ are the solution of the $ \epsilon $ form and the $ \lambda $ form respectively.

You may see an example in my answer at [Cross Validated Question 291962](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/338229/6244).

Answer (score 3):

This parameter control sparsity of the basis. Look for articles on L1 norm "oracle property". In essence, by minimizing the L1 norm you're driving your representation to have few non-zero components. The lambda tunes how much of your squared error vs. L1 norm you pay most attention to. Large lambda means you care a lot about sparsity, but not exact matching. Small lambda gives you the opposite. This can also be looked at as a bias-variance tradeoff of your learner.

Comment: It's not the sparsity of the basis. It is the sparsity of the coordinate vector.