# Solving LASSO (Basis Pursuit Denoising Form) with LARS

Tags: matlab, compressive-sensing, optimization, convex-optimization, sparse-model

I'm now working on using LARS (Least Angle Regression) algorithm to solve a LASSO problem in Basis Pursuit Denoising form like:

\begin{align*}
\quad && \arg \min_{\beta}{\left\| y - X\beta \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \beta \right\|}_{1} && (1)
\end{align*}

I have done many search jobs on the web, what confused me is LARS is more like an algorithm to solve problems in this form:

\begin{align*}
\quad & \arg \min_{\beta} {\left\| y - X\beta \right\|}_{2}^{2} 
&& \text{subject to.} && {\left\| \beta\right\|}_{1} \leq t && (2)
\end{align*}

I know these two forms is equal to each other in theory and LARS can solve problem(1) for all 0<λ≤∞.
But I want know how to use LARS to solve problem(1) in practice, which means how can I write a function like:

```
function lars(X, y, lambda){
 ...
 return beta;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your $||\cdot||$ denotes a two-norm and your $|\cdot|$ denotes a one-norm? In this case, as far as I know, the following is true: for every $\lambda$ in (1) there exists a $t$ in (2) such that (1) and (2) give the same solution. However, I wouldn't know of any explicit way to convert one into the other and I would claim this is not easy. But I'm curious if other folks around here know more. Btw: might also be a fitting question for Math.Stackexchange (I mean how to find $t$ given $\lambda$).

Comment: Please use LaTeX for the math expressions. See [MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: Related https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21730, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21734, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291962. Pay attention that the connection between $ \lambda $ and $ \epsilon $ is data dependent. See my linked answers.

Comment: Yes,  ||⋅|| denotes a L2-norm and |⋅| denotes a L1-norm.  @Florian

Comment: I'll try to edit it use LaTeX.   @Royi

Comment: I added the answer. Pay attention that LARS is Homotopy solver. Namely it generates the whole path of solutions for the problem.

Comment: I know LARS generates the whole path of solution. So, how can I use LARS to get a solution for a given λ in practice @Royi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 forms of the Basis Pursuit problem:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{The $ \lambda $ Form:} & \quad && \arg \min_{x} &&\frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{The $ \epsilon$ Form:} && \quad & \arg \min_{x} && {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
&& \quad & \text{subject to} && \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} \leq \epsilon
\end{align*}$$

Real world model is:

$$ A x = y $$

Where $ x $ is a sparse vector.
Yet, in reality we don't have measurements of $ y $ but $ b = y + v $ where $ v $ is a vector with the properties of our measurement method.

Hence we allow the model not to have strict equality which implies:

$$ {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} \leq \epsilon = {\left\| v \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Now, the different models are equivalent as for any $ \epsilon $ there is a $ \lambda $ (Which depends on $ A $ and $ b $ unfortunately) which the models ( (1) and (2) ) are equivalent.

For instance I created simple simulation on for that simulation:

[image]

The full code is available on my [StackExchange Cross Validated Q291962 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q291962` folder).

Since you linked to the paper you're reading - [Sparse Geometric Representation Through Local Shape Probing](https://perso.liris.cnrs.fr/julie.digne/articles/lpf.pdf) the problem solved there is the $ \lambda $ form.
Since it is a strict Convex Problem there is a single solution. LARS isn't considered a very efficient or fast method to solve the problem, hence I recommend using a different solution.

I have a project with many solvers of the [$ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Least Squares](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects). I suggest you just take the [Proximal Gradient Method - `SolveLsL1Prox.m`](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects) or the [Accelerated Proximal Gradient Descent Method - `SolveLsL1ProxAccel.m`](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects).

So you can just pick any of those MATLAB codes and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked your github repo, but I didn't find LARS code which is my primary goal.

Comment: The idea is you'll have to do what I did in the code. For any solution of LARS to check the value of the objective function in $ \lambda $ form. By the way, it makes no sense to solve this in that way.

Comment: Thanks again for your patient, but I'm still confused. I ask this question because there is a paper use LARS to solve a problem like (1) in my post. I want to implement that paper, so I have to figure it out.

Comment: Give us a link to the paper. Again, you can do it, but you will have to analyze each solution of the LARS.

Comment: the paper link : https://perso.liris.cnrs.fr/julie.digne/articles/lpf.pdf , "lars" is mentioned in section 3.3

Comment: If you're after solving the problem, why do you insist on this method? This is a convex problem, any solver will have the same solution.

Comment: Well, my initial thought was to be consistent with that paper, so that the running time and accuracy of my code can be consistent with the author's. If there is no good way, I will try other solvers.

Comment: It might be that the authors are not very knowledgeable in this field of solving $ {L}_{1} $ regularized least squares. There are many more modern solvers with much better run time and efficiency. I solved it many times on this site. I can add solution if you want.

Comment: That would be great ! Please.

Comment: I added links to my MATLAB solvers for this problem. They are easy to use and efficient solving the problem. Enjoy...

Comment: I'll check it. Thanks a lot !